# Usage of articles with biological terminology

Tags: articles

In the following sentence

> The hippocampus plays an important role in the formation of emotion
>   and memory consolidation.

my teacher pointed out that article *The* in front of the word *hippocampus* is incorrect, and *A* should be used instead. As in

> A hippocampus plays an important role in the formation of emotion
>   and memory consolidation.

I disagree. Who do you think is right?

Answer (score 6):

You are correct, your teacher is wrong. It's perfectly appropriate to use definite article to refers to the kind of object in general.

You can use Google Scholar to search for text in scientific publications. The results are pretty damning:

- [*A hippocampus plays an important role*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22A%20hippocampus%20plays%20an%20important%20role%22): 0 results
- [*The hippocampus plays an important role*](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22The%20hippocampus%20plays%20an%20important%20role%22): 1,410 results